# Bind Properties of two different ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

Again I have a problem:

I have two existing MVVM pattern.
All ViewModels are base on ViewModelBase of MVVM light.

PlugList - PlugListViewModel - PlugListView  (Displays a list of plugs)
Plug - PlugViewModel - PlugView (Displays properties of a specific plug)

Both views are already used at different places.
Now I need another view which provides me a window where both ViewModels are combined:

PlugListViewModel_Window - PlugListView_Window

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <View:View_PlugList x:Name="PlugListView" DataContext="{Binding Path=ViewModel_PlugList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <View:View_Plug x:Name="PlugList" DataContext="{Binding ViewModel_Plug}" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class ViewModel_PlugListWindow : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel_PlugListWindow()
    {
    }

    private const string ViewModel_PlugList_PropertyName = "ViewModel_PlugList";
    private ViewModel_PlugList _ViewModel_PlugList;
    public ViewModel_PlugList ViewModel_PlugList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ViewModel_PlugList;
        }
        set
        {
            _ViewModel_PlugList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ViewModel_PlugList_PropertyName);
        }
    }

    private const string ViewModel_Plug_PropertyName = "ViewModel_Plug";
    private ViewModel_Plug _ViewModel_Plug;
    public ViewModel_Plug ViewModel_Plug
    {
        get
        {
            return _ViewModel_Plug;
        }
        set
        {
            _ViewModel_Plug = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ViewModel_Plug_PropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

All properties in the viewmodels are defined like the following example:

```
private const string SelectedPlugPropertyName = "SelectedPlug";
private RaControlPlug _SelectedPlug;
public RaControlPlug SelectedPlug
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedPlug;
    }
    private set
    {
        _SelectedPlug = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedPlugPropertyName);
    }
}
```

**PlugListView:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="RaControlRuleConfig.View.View_PlugList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"               
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:RaControlRuleConfig.ViewModel"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RaControlRuleConfig"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Add Plug" Command="{Binding AddPlugCommand}"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PlugList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlug}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RaControlPlug}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Now I would like to bind a variable of PlugListViewModel to PlugViewModel.
(SelectedPlug should be the plug in the PlugViewModel.

How to arrange that?

Thank you!

Comment: `Now I would like to bind a variable of PlugListViewModel to PlugViewModel.` And that makes no sense.

Comment: This is not MVVM as I know it. You have, apparently, one model to one viewmodel to one view. I'm not going to say it's wrong, but it seems unusual. Can you post any code that shows how your PlugListView is put together?

Comment: I have provided some more code for you. Is this guy doing it in the right way? [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1037)

Answer (score 0):

You've not *quite* got the pattern down right. Your linked example uses a MainViewModel to provide backing logic for both a SingleUser View and a UserList View. Because they use the same ViewModel the two Views are working from the same property values. There's no communication between the Views, the Views are just showing data from the same ViewModel.

Your posted code above shows *two* ViewModel classes, which is what's causing problems. You should, I think, have a single ViewModel class dealing with all Plug related logic. This ViewModel will likely have:

```
ObservableCollection<Plug> Plugs
Plug SelectedPlug
```

Where Plugs is the ItemsSource for the ListView in your posted code, and SelectedPlug is the SelectedItem.

Comment: So it's not possible to use my 2 existing views combined in one view? That's not good because i have to generate a new view totally equal the other 2 combined.

Comment: You can. You need to set the DataContext of your 2 Views to *the same ViewModel* to have it behave the same way as the code in the link you posted. That ViewModel needs to have properties which match the properties required by your View.

Comment: That meas I have to implement savecommands and so on twice? :(

Comment: Why would you have to implement them twice?

Comment: Because ViewModelPlugList needs the same properties, commands,.. like ViewModelPlugListWindow?